# Как добавить точки на гугл карту, сгенерированные php

Tags: javascript, php

нужно в js добавить точки на карте, которые тащаться с mysql. Как это реализовать.

пробовал распечатать пхп в див, а потом в js файл вставить var nemap = $('#map').html(); но оно наверно не как объекты вставляеться как реализовать правильно?

сами точки, которые нужно аменить на текст с php

```js
var features = [{
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(57.573117, 49.770054),
     content: '<div class="map-baloon__title">TMT RUSSIA</div>' + '<div class="map-baloon__content">' + '<a class="map-baloon__instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/themoneyteamshop/" target="_blank"><svg><use xlink:href="images/sprites.svg#instagram"></use></svg>OPEN INSTAGRAM</a>' + '</div>',
     type: 'info'
    }, {
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(24.248561, 49.277894),
     content: '<div class="map-baloon__title">TMT</div>' + '<div class="map-baloon__content">' + '<a class="map-baloon__instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/themoneyteamshop/" target="_blank"><svg><use xlink:href="images/sprites.svg#instagram"></use></svg>OPEN INSTAGRAM</a>' + '</div>',
     type: 'info'
    }, {
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91747, 151.22912),
     content: '<div class="map-baloon__title">TMT</div>' + '<div class="map-baloon__content">' + '<a class="map-baloon__instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/themoneyteamshop/" target="_blank"><svg><use xlink:href="images/sprites.svg#instagram"></use></svg>OPEN INSTAGRAM</a>' + '</div>',
     type: 'info'
    }];
```

вот часть кода куда нужно вставить

```html
var initMap = function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('footer-map'), {
     center: {
      lat: 37.118944,
      lng: -128.142917
     },
     zoom: 2,
     disableDefaultUI: false,
     disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
     draggable: true,
     fullscreenControl: false,
     keyboardShortcuts: false,
     panControl: false,
     scrollwheel: false
    });

    /*marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coordinates,
        map: map
    });*/
    var iconBase = '/images/sprites/';
    var icons = {
     info: {
      icon: iconBase + 'marker.svg'
     }
    };

    var features = [{
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(57.573117, 49.770054),
     content: '<div class="map-baloon__title">TMT RUSSIA</div>' + '<div class="map-baloon__content">' + '<a class="map-baloon__instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/themoneyteamshop/" target="_blank"><svg><use xlink:href="images/sprites.svg#instagram"></use></svg>OPEN INSTAGRAM</a>' + '</div>',
     type: 'info'
    }, {
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(24.248561, 49.277894),
     content: '<div class="map-baloon__title">TMT</div>' + '<div class="map-baloon__content">' + '<a class="map-baloon__instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/themoneyteamshop/" target="_blank"><svg><use xlink:href="images/sprites.svg#instagram"></use></svg>OPEN INSTAGRAM</a>' + '</div>',
     type: 'info'
    }, {
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91747, 151.22912),
     content: '<div class="map-baloon__title">TMT</div>' + '<div class="map-baloon__content">' + '<a class="map-baloon__instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/themoneyteamshop/" target="_blank"><svg><use xlink:href="images/sprites.svg#instagram"></use></svg>OPEN INSTAGRAM</a>' + '</div>',
     type: 'info'
    }];

    var _loop = function _loop(i) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: features[i].position,
      icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
      map: map,
      content: features[i].content
     });

     markers.push(marker);

     google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function(e) {
      this.setMap(null);

      var infoBox = new InfoBox({
       latlng: this.position,
       map: map,
       content: this.content,
       marker: i
      });
     });
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
     _loop(i);
    }

    $.getJSON('/js/googleMapStyle.json', function(data) {
     map.setOptions({
      styles: data
     });
    });
   };

   initMap();
  }
```

Comment: Создал json, вроде все как нужно но точки не создаются. Почему?   $maps = MapsBoks::get();

      $pointmaps = array();

      foreach($maps as $map){
          $pointmaps[] = array(
              "position" => "new google.maps.LatLng(57.573117, 49.770054)",   
              "type" => "info",
          );
      }

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать маркеры таким способом

```
var markers = features.map(function (feature) {
    return addMarker(feature, map);
});

function addMarker(feature, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon
        map: map
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: feature.content    
    });
    marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });
    return marker;
}
```

рекомендую использовать функцию

> Array.prototype.map

для итерации массива